# Creating 3D surface plots using in Plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, surface

I am trying to create a 3D surface plot using three 1D arrays of floats in Plotly. This is what my data looks like:

```
    alpha_1 alpha_2   sse
0   0.01    0.01    4.817321e+07
1   0.01    0.11    4.854821e+07
2   0.01    0.21    4.864922e+07
3   0.01    0.31    4.869423e+07
4   0.01    0.41    4.870884e+07
... ... ... ...
95  0.91    0.51    4.859500e+07
96  0.91    0.61    4.857550e+07
97  0.91    0.71    4.855622e+07
98  0.91    0.81    4.853898e+07
99  0.91    0.91    4.852403e+07
```

I want to create a surface plot that basically mimics this 3d plot.
This is the code I am using to generate the 3D plot:  [see here 3D plot I want to make as surface plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMgY7.png)

```
x = np.asarray(surface_df['alpha_1'])
y = np.asarray(surface_df['alpha_2'])
z = np.asarray(surface_df['sse'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=z);
plt.show()
```

But this is the surface plot I am getting with Plotly.
[Surface plot from Plotly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyH4Z.png)

This is the code I am using for plotly.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=surface_df['alpha_1'].values,y=surface_df['alpha_2'].values,z=surface_df[['alpha_1','sse','alpha_2']].values)])

fig.update_layout(title='plot', autosize=True,
                  width=500, height=500)
fig.show()
```

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: may be this is a good start [here](https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create 2-D array in order to plot surface.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

#Read data
data = pd.read_csv('your_data_set.txt', header=0, delimiter='\t')

#Create meshgrid for x,y
xi = np.linspace(min(data['alpha_1']), max(data['alpha_1']), num=100)
yi = np.linspace(min(data['alpha_2']), max(data['alpha_2']), num=100)

x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

#Grid data
z_grid = griddata((data['alpha_1'],data['alpha_2']),data['sse'],(x_grid,y_grid),method='cubic')

# Plotly 3D Surface
fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(x=x_grid,y=y_grid,z=z_grid,
                       colorscale='viridis'))

fig.show()
```

[additional information about gridding methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)